# NewSQL a drop a replacement?

Tags: mysql, oracle, nosql

Been looking and reading into NewSQL implementations lately such as ScaleDB, Clusterix, VoltDB etc...
According to this term, it is a scalable, relational database and supports the SQL language similar to MySQL/Oracle.

Does it mean that It's a drop in replacement for MySQL/Oracle?  What about complex queries?

It seem to be promising and advertising itself as a drop in replacement, how much of that is actually a fact.  My guess is, similar to NoSQL, this would sit in front of traditional RDBMS systems such as Oracle only to serve high transactional data but still rely on a more stable backend system to maintain/hold data?

Insight and thoughts would be appreciated on this topic.

Comment: I recently helped author a blog post (disclaimer: I work at Clustrix) on exactly this topic: http://www.clustrix.com/blog/bid/250365/What-Does-it-Mean-to-Say-Clustrix-is-a-MySQL-Replacement

Answer (score 5):

There are two types of NewSQL databases:

1)  **SQL compliant databases** developed from the ground up to overcome RDBMS scalability challenges while retaining benefits such as ACID with immediate consistency and data durability.  To facilitate faster deployment, some of the solutions feature MySQL emulation and can be used as a drop-in replacement to get immediate scalability benefits, high availability and consolidation of multiple MySQL databases into one easier to manage system.

2)  **RDBMS add-ons** that enhance an existing RDBMS such as MySQL to scale or replicate better.  You would typically run multiple MySQL servers, and the add-on would connect them into a greater whole that performs better.

Clustrix and VoltDB fall into the first category.  ScaleDB into the second.  Check out the customer case studies for each to get a better feel for how these solutions have either replaced or enhanced an existing RDBMS deployment.  The best is that these solutions offer the benefits of a relational database while scaling like NoSQL - no need to rewrite the application.

Comment: Thanks very helpfull for a newbie of newSQL like me. Do you have any other examples for the second category you described beside ScaleDB?